# Drupal 7 Node reference field in Views only visible to administrator

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views, nodereference

I have a Content type that uses a Node Reference as a field and a second field which is a Term Reference.

I have created a view that shows ALL the Term references and a field from the node if that term has been used. See example below

Term1
Term2 - Node Title 1
Term3
Term4 - Node Title 2
Term5
Term6

This views works great if I am logged in as Admin, but shows nothing if I am logged in as a user, even the user who created the nodes.

I am at a loss as to what to check next.

Answer (score 0):

I'd check which roles can view these nodetypes, also which roles can view these terms. Also check permissions for the view itself.